# Loops with variables that count- trying to find out where this ends

Tags: python, loops, while-loop, counting

I'm supposed to type the programs output. Input is 6, 3

```
target = int(input())
n = int(input())
while n <= target:
    print(n * 2)
    n += 1 

My output - 6
```

My reasoning- 3 < 6 so the code will run through. 3 * 2 = 6 so 6 gets printed out. Then we do 6 += 1 which would be 7. 7 is not <= 6 so code shouldn't run through again.

```
The expected output: 
    6
    8
    10
    12
```

n += 1 is shorthand for n = n + 1. The loop ends when n is greater than target.

Can someone please tell me where I am going wrong?

Comment: The last output is from 6 * 2, which means n was less than or equal to 6.

Answer (score 0):

`print(n * 2)` does not affect the value of `n`. Since we did not put `n * 2` in the value of `n`, the value of `n` changes only by `n += 1`.

```
target = int(input())
n = int(input())
while n <= target:
    n = n * 2
    print(n)
    n += 1
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the main difference between `print` and `return` statement.
Using return changes the flow of the program. Using print does not

```
def func(target,n):
    while n <= target:
        return (n * 2)
        n += 1 
target = int(input())
n = int(input())
print(func(target,n))
```

[See here](https://pythonprinciples.com/blog/print-vs-return/)

Answer (score 0):

this might be a little late since you posted your question last year, but I was stuck with the same problem last night for hours and could not figure it out on my own. So, I googled it and your question (and not an answer anywhere) popped up here. So I kept working. Finally, I figured it out a few minutes ago and I am going to write my solution here:

I start the process with my second input n=3 and since n< 6, it goes through the first loop: 3 * 2 =6
then I have to increment my 'n' but stop before it reaches my target which is 6:

(3*2)=6
((3+1)*2)=8
(((3+1)+1)*2)=10 note that my incremented n (inside parentheses) is 5 and still less than 6 so I keep going

((((3+1)+1)+1))*2)= 12 here is when I have to stop because my incremented n has reached the target that is 6 <=6
so my response will be:
6
8
10
12